# Rails update three way join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a 'Rails way' to update a three column join table on a single form? I have three models, `User`, `Location`, `Role` and a three column join table `UserLocationRole`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :user_location_roles
  has_many :locations, through: :user_location_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_location_roles
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has_many through etc
end 

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has_many through etc
end

class UserLocationRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :role
end
```

What I'd like is on the New/Edit User form to see a list of checkboxes:

```
1. Location: ABC
   [] Role 1
   [] Role 2
   [] Role 3
2. Location: DEF
   [] Role 1
   [] Role 2
   [] Role 3
```

The number of locations and roles in my use case are small (typically 2 or 3 locations with 3 roles), so this form will never be too large/awkward. I specifically want to list all Roles in each location, i.e. I do not want a role to be directly connected to a location (there is no location_id column in the roles table).

I've created a solution that feels very 'un-Railsy', and am wondering if there is a cleaner way to go with e.g. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` etc.

My solution:
User Controller:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @permissions = @user.user_location_roles # used to make sure appropriate checkboxes are ticked on the form.
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  @user.set_permissions(params[:user_permissions])
  @user.save #etc
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.set_permissions(params[:user_permissions])
  @user.update #etc
end
```

My form iterates through all possible locations and then prints a checkbox for each possible role. It checks if that specific record exists in the join table already, and sets the 'checked' flag to true if so.

```
<% @user.company.locations.all.each do |location| %>
  <p><%= location.name %></p>
  <% @user.company.roles.all.each do |role| %>
    <% checked = (@permissions) ? (@permissions.select { |p| p.location == location and p.role == role  }.any?) : false %>
    <label><%= check_box_tag "user_permissions[#{location.id}][#{role.id}]", "1", checked %><%= role.name %></label><br> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My user model then takes the subsequent hash from the form, deletes all the entries in the join table for that user (very ugly) and then creates new ones as required.

```
def set_permissions(permissions_hash)
  self.user_location_roles.destroy_all
  permissions_hash.each do |location_id, roles_hash|
    roles_hash.each do |role_id, bool|
      self.user_location_roles.build(location_id: location_id, role_id: role_id)
    end
  end
end
```

Please help me refactor my code into something cleaner. At the very least, I should not need to delete all the permissions and re-create them if a user form is submitted without a change to the permissions. Ideally there is a much cleaner way to produce the form output as well. Thanks.

Comment: Your form should be submitting to a `UserLocationRolesController`, which creates/edits/destroys instances of the join model.

Comment: @MaxWilliams this is a `User` editing form, where a user edits e.g. their address or other personal details as well as setting their roles for each location. In that context I don't think it makes sense to submit the form to anything other than the `UsersController`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form to update nested objects in a single form.

Comment: That railscast is useful for updating actual nested objects, I do not see how it helps to update a 3 way association table rather than the objects themselves.